# Possible memory leakage with the following MOSS 2007 code?

Tags: sharepoint, moss

Does the below code leaks memory?  If so, any recommendations on optimising it?

```
SPWeb web = (SPWeb)properties.Feature.Parent; // comes from the event receiver
//... lots of other code

// the below is the focal point.
foreach (SPWeb childWeb in web.Webs) 
{
    try
    {
        // lots of heavy processing with the childWebs
    }
    finally
    {
        if (childWeb != null)
        {
            childWeb.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you have posted should be fine. However, depending on what you do with the childWeb within the try-statement, it might cause memory leaks. Can you post the entire code? Do you suspect memory leaks?

Comment: Thanks for the check.  I only do very light processing with the childWeb e.g. getting lists.  I was being paranoid that doing a foreach on webs might potentially cause a leak, since after some failed code, the entire browser seems to get stuck on Detecting Proxy Settings for ages before coming back to life again.   And I thought that might be because of an IISreset caused by memory leak.

Comment: Ok, no problem. You can always monitor the w3wp-process in the Task Manager, to see if it actually performs an iisreset, in which case, the memory usage of that process should drop.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Disposing Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee557362.aspx), your code matches the Good Coding Practice for SPWeb.Webs.

As mentioned on that page, I would recommend downloading and using [SPDisposeCheck](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/SPDisposeCheck) as both verification of correct code and identification of potential memory leaks.